# Create one df from multiple dfs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple pd dfs like this:

```
df1 = [nan nan nan   1
       nan   2 nan nan
       nan nan nan nan]

df2 = [  1 nan nan nan
       nan nan nan nan
       nan nan nan   4]

df3 = [nan nan nan nan
         5 nan   3 nan
       nan nan nan nan]
```

Now I want to create a new df with the column entries which are not nan. The result should look like this:

```
df1 = [  1 nan nan   1
         5   2   3 nan
       nan nan nan   4]
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `np.maximum(df1, df2, df3)`?

Comment: I think you need `np.maximum.reduce` @quang

Comment: Unfortunately all entries in the new df are nan, when I try this @QuangHoang

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example @betty? So `df1=pd.DataFrame(...)` and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a concat:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2,df3]).groupby(level=0).first()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

Replace `nan` values with 0. then perform `np.amax` with `axis=0`

```
df1 = [['nan', 'nan', 'nan',   1],
       ['nan',   2, 'nan', 'nan'],
       ['nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan']]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df1 = df1.replace('nan', 0, regex=True)

df2 = [[1, 'nan', 'nan',   'nan'],
       ['nan',   'nan', 'nan', 'nan'],
       ['nan', 'nan', 'nan', 4]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
df2 = df2.replace('nan', 0, regex=True)

df3 = [['nan', 'nan', 'nan',   'nan'],
       [5,   'nan', 3, 'nan'],
       ['nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan']]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df3)
df3 = df3.replace('nan', 0, regex=True)

output_arr = np.amax(np.array([df1.values, df2.values, df3.values]),axis=0)
output_df = pd.DataFrame(output_arr)
output_df = output_df.replace(0,'nan', regex=True)
output_df
```

output:

[image]